# How can I solve my StringBuilder problem?

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

**What I am doing:** Replacing variables within a string using `StringBuilder` to generate questions that contain variation.

```
string question;

void CreateNewQuestion()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int questionNumber = rnd.Next(1, 4); //Generate a random question number
    int a = rnd.Next(1, 10); //Create random numbers so the question is different each time
    int b = rnd.Next(1, 15);
    int c = rnd.Next(1, 15);

    string q = questionNumber.ToString(); 

    StringBuilder sbq = new StringBuilder("Question" +q);//StringBuilder is now called to replace the randomly called for question with its new variables
    sbq.Replace("Question1", $"What is {a} + {a} ?");
    sbq.Replace("Question2", $"What is {a} + {b} ?");
    sbq.Replace("Question3", $"What is {a*c} + {a} ?"");

    question = sbq.ToString();
}
```

**The problem:** If string `q` (the one being modified) = "Question1", `StringBuilder.Replace` won't just stop at `sb.Replace("Question1"...)` it will still calculate for Question 2 and 3. Thus as the number of questions increases, so does the inefficiency of this.

**The question:** How can I create questions that contain variables so as to provide variation within the same question structure in an efficient manner?

Comment: To increase the readability I suggest you to use the following form: `$"What is {a} + {b}?"`. It helps a lot, especially in your case in which string conjunction + are mixed with mathematical +.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense.  You put "Question" + q into a string, but then immediately replace it with something else that doesn't have anything to do with a question number.

Comment: Hi, updated to do so - I hope it helps

Comment: @Robert Harvey, if you don't do that then the item being replaced would just be the number. Each time that number is then generated and featured in a question StringBuilder will treat that as something that needs replacing. So, it needs to be "Question" + the question number to avoid that.

Comment: Ok, if you really have three different variations (and only three) of the questions, just use `if else` statements or a switch case.  `if (questionNumber == 1) { do something } else if (questionNumber == 2) { do something else }`.  That makes your calculations mutually exclusive.

Comment: If you have more than three, you probably need a different approach.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions which are much more more complex this is just a simplified version - do you have any suggestions on the different approach?

Comment: Then I would put the strings `"What is {a} + {b}?"` in an array or dictionary, and look them up by question number.  Make them formatting strings so that you can still fill in the holes.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: I think you got it all wrong.... StringBuilder would be better used to build the questions rather than "replacing"......  That is the power of the StringBuilder.

Comment: @Robert Harvey can the array of formatting strings and random number generation be in separate functions, so they can be combined to provide new questions? I am attempting your solution and getting the same number replacing {a} unless number generation and array creation are done in the same function

Comment: Yes, they can be in separate functions.  I would have to see your code to know what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will keep trying before having to keep asking for your help and time and return if I remain stuck

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have had to give in and ask for further help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60568058/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-string-interpolation-in-c if you do get any time it would be greatly appreciated and if not thank you for everything so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`:

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
 int questionNumber = rnd.Next(1, 4); //Generate a random question number
 int a = rnd.Next(1, 10); //Create random numbers so the question is different each time
 int b = rnd.Next(1, 15);
 int c = rnd.Next(1, 15);            

 var questions = new Dictionary<int, string>
 {
     { 1, "What is " + a + " + " + a + " ?" },
     { 2, "What is " + a + " + " + b + " ?" },
     { 3, "What is " + (a * b) + " + " + c + " ?" },
 };

 var question = string.Empty;
 if (questions.TryGetValue(questionNumber, out question))
 {
     // key exists and you can read your question here
 }
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to have a dictionary to be created in one function and the random numbers in another, then you it is necessary to have one goal functions:

```
static Random rnd = new Random();
static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    int questionQuantity = 15;
    var questions = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < questionQuantity; i++)
    {
        int variableCount = rnd.Next(17);
        var variables = CreateVariables(variableCount);
        var signs = CreateSigns(variableCount - 1);
        var question = CreateQuestion(variables, signs);
        questions.Add(i, question);
    }  
}
```

And other functions:

```
public static List<int> CreateVariables(int variableQuantity)
{
    var variables = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < variableQuantity; i++)
    {
         variables.Add(rnd.Next(1, 15));
    }
    return variables;
}

public static List<char> CreateSigns(int variableQuantity)
{
    var operators = new char[] {'+', '-', '/', '*' };
    var randomOperators = new List<char>();
    for (int i = 0; i < variableQuantity; i++)
    {
        randomOperators.Add(operators[ rnd.Next(0, 3) ]);
    }
    return randomOperators;
}

public static string CreateQuestion(List<int> variables, List<char> operations)
{   
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("What is ");
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < variables.Count; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(variables[i]);                
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            sb.Append(" ");
            sb.Append(operations[j]);
            sb.Append(" ");
            j++;
        }   
    }
    sb.Append("?");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: use an array folk, access it by index

Comment: @irdis: Arrays are of fixed size.

Comment: @Irdis Dictionary<TKey, TValue> is used in case OP wants to have key as `string` value, e.g., `Question1`, as he said in his question.

Comment: I would combine this answer with a StringBuilder to build the ouput.

Comment: @StepUp Can the dictionary be created in one function and the random numbers in another, so that the random numbers could generate them - then grab a question from the dictionary and combine the both? Instead of both questions and numbers having to be generated at the same time? Thank you

Comment: That's a work of art, thank you! What an incredible answer

Comment: @kizzer thank you very much! It means the whole world for me! Have a great day! :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a switch statement

```
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int a = rnd.Next(1, 10); //Create random numbers so the question is different each time
        int b = rnd.Next(1, 15);
        int c = rnd.Next(1, 15);
        string question;

        switch (rnd.Next(1, 4)) {
            case 1: {
                question = "What is " + a + " + " + a + " ?";

                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                question = "What is " + a + " + " + b + " ?";

                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                question = "What is " + (a * b) + " + " + c + " ?";

                break;
            }
            default: {
                question = "Default Value";

                break;
            }
        }
```

C# 8:

```
        question = rnd.Next(1, 4) switch {
            1 => "What is " + a + " + " + a + " ?",
            2 => "What is " + a + " + " + b + " ?",
            3 => "What is " + (a * b) + " + " + c + " ?",
            _ => "Default Value"
        };
```

Comment: Hi PeterT, could I then put the ints within a function that is called at the start of each case? So each time the question is generated new variables will be selected? And would you suggest this as efficient? Thank you

Comment: @kizzer do you mean pass ints to a function, where this switch statement is, to then return results?