# What am I doing wrong with string interpolation in c#?

Tags: c#, string, string-interpolation

**What I am doing:** I am trying to build a dictionary in one function (`DictionaryBuilder`), extract a string from said dictionary and apply variables to it in another function (`QuestionGenerator`). Thus each time `QuestionBuilder` is called, the same string will be returned with differing contents without having to remake the same dictionary repeatedly.

```
        int a;
        int b;
        string theQuestion;
        string theAnswer;
        Dictionary<string, string> questionDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        void DictionaryBuilder()
        {
            questionDict.Add("0", $"What is {a} x {b} ?");
            questionDict.Add("1", $"The sum of {a} x {b} = {a*b}");
        }

        void QuestionGenerator()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            a = rnd.Next(1, 10);
            b = rnd.Next(1, 10);
            theQuestion = questionDict["0"];
            theAnswer = questionDict["1"];
            Console.WriteLine(theQuestion);
            Console.WriteLine(theAnswer);
        }
```

**Current results:** "What is 0 x 0?" and "The sum of 0 and 0 is 0". I cannot get the new numbers to be applied.

**Question:** How do I make this work so I can have the creation of the dictionary and the variables separate so as that each time `QuestionGenerator` is called a new question of the same format is provided without needing to repeatedly rebuild the dictionary (which I assume is very inefficient)?

`QuestionGenerator` is called by the click of a button, so as to generate a new question in the same format.

*(Please note: The actual dictionary and calculations will be far larger, more complex and the questions and answers will not be in the same dictionary - this was just for example simplicity.)*

Comment: `QuestionGenerator` is called by the click of a button, so as to generate a new question in the same format.

Comment: @Amy: It is a follow-up question.  The original question is about something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dictionary containing your string templates

```
Dictionary<string, string> questionDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

void DictionaryBuilder()
{
    questionDict.Add("0", "What is {a} x {b} ?");
    questionDict.Add("1", "The sum of {a} x {b} = {a*b}");
}
```

and then use `String.Format()` on the retrieved string to compose your question.

```
theQuestion = string.Format(questionDict["0"], a, b);
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help today!! (and kind patience!)

Answer (score 4):

You should turn questionDict into a dictionary with Functions as values, not strings:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<string>> questionDict = new Dictionary<string, Func<string>>();

void DictionaryBuilder()
{
    questionDict.Add("0", () => $"What is {a} x {b} ?");
    questionDict.Add("1", () => $"The sum of {a} x {b} = {a*b}");
}
```

Then set your variables via call of those functions:

```
theQuestion = questionDict["0"]();
theAnswer = questionDict["1"]();
```

This allows you to capture the state of affairs (the values of `a` and `b`) at the time you call the function.

Comment: Don't you have to pass `a` and `b` somehow?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, you could set it up that way, but as long as `a` and `b` are in scope you don't have to.  Before posting I ran code with variables `a` and `b` at the same level of the methods, as the OP has it set up, and it worked fine.

Comment: That's a really neat trick.  Of course, it could be avoided by simply using `string.Format` on the retrieved string instead of relying on string interpolation and function delegates.

Comment: pwilcox thank you so much! The relief is unreallll!!!! @RobertHarvey I would not have been able to solve this without you either, you help has been so valuable thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the string are interpolated at the time of the `DictionaryBuilder()` call. strings are not "dynamically" interpolated.

When you create your dictionary, the strings are calculated once with the initial values at that time of a and b, that are both 0.

You would need to create a small one line method for that, you can for instance use a dictionary that stores a `Func<string>`instead of string.

Comment: and the [answer from pwilcox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60568176/479251) is the code example of the last sentence :)